# XPath Wordpress Scraper plugin

Tags: regex, xpath

I'm trying to scrape the city and the state separately using either XPath or Regex. I'm able to select both city and state, separated by comma, such as

Trail, BC ([page link](https://ca.indeed.com/viewjob?cmp=Record-Ridge-Denture-Clinic-Inc&t=Office%20Assistant&jk=8258bd5744ff4272&vjs=3))

by Xpath:

```
//div[contains(text(), ",")])[1]
/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]
```

or by Regex:

```
([A-z]+)(,\s)(AB|BC|ON)
```

However, when I try to scrape either City or Province by substring-before and after, such as:
Xpath 2.0 `//div[contains(text(), ",")])[1]/substring-after(text(),",")`
or Xpath 1.0 `substring-after(//div[contains(text(), ",")])[1],",")`

The [plugin](https://preview.codecanyon.net/item/scraper-automatic-content-crawl-and-post-plugin-for-wordpress/full_screen_preview/22458136) is unable to return the city only. Is it anything wrong in the syntax?

Comment: If you are using regex, then can't you just refer the captured groups ?

Comment: The XPath expressions seem extremely brittle. The page source identifies a pretty neatly formatted JSON element named `jobLocation` for you to pull out.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative XPath expressions.

```
//span[@data-indeed-apply-joblocation]/@data-indeed-apply-joblocation
```

Output : `Trail, BC`

```
substring-before(//span[@data-indeed-apply-joblocation]/@data-indeed-apply-joblocation,",")
```

Output : `Trail`

```
substring-after(//span[@data-indeed-apply-joblocation]/@data-indeed-apply-joblocation,", ")
```

Output : `BC`

**EDIT** : Since substring functions are not supported, use a regex to clean the result. Keep the XPath I've provided (set the "Part" in the right panel to "Text Content"). Then, in the "Tranform" menu ("Advance mode" in the right panel), under "Find & Replace", input the following regex :

```
^.+,\W
```

Replace with nothing.

Output :

[image: OP]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Anyway, I figured out how to select, but not sure the language plugin is using. It can't crawl with the substring-before and after.

Comment: Well, it seems the plugin has a "Transform" menu where you can clean the result. Post has been edited.